# Mongodb - watch changestream in documents with nested array element of certain value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pipeline, watch, changestream

Here is my document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6257a55d04bf2167733f5b72"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "CustomerName": "John",
        "CustomerID": "28374",
        "LoanID": "82349327409234"
        "type": "Record",
        "Pointers": [
           {"type":"car","token_id":"123"},
           {"type":"house","token_id":"456"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my watch query aiming to watch for Pointers elements with type:"car":

```
var watchCursor = db.loans.watch([
  {
    $match: {
      "$or": [
        {
          "updateDescription.updatedFields.attributes.Pointers": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "type": "car"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fullDocument.attributes.Pointers": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "type": "car"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
   if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
      print(JSON.stringify(watchCursor.next()));
   }
}
```

The problem is that I alter the document but it does not return any change results.

As a test, I changed the `$elemMatch` stage to `$exists: true`, then alter the document and it returned the changed document successfully.

what's wrong?!

Comment: This is working perfectly fine for me. I can see docs in the console on updates. On other note, I think elemMatch is totally unnecessary, you can simply use " "$or": [  {"updateDescription.updatedFields.attributes.Pointers.type": "car" },  { fullDocument.attributes.Pointers.type": "car" }]  " to achieve same thing.

Comment: I just noticed some formatting errors with the sample data I pushed into the database. Now it's working fine :)